# iOS - Diceroll increase frequency of one object

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

In my application ammo is being dropped when an enemy is killed. There are 4 different types of ammo with this code `int diceRoll = arc4random() % 3; //0 to 3` Each ammo type has now a frequency of 25% for being spawned. Is it possible to make for example ammo type 2 to become more frequent? for example up to 40% so the other ammo type will be 20%

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
int spaceSet = pow(10, 3); //range of 1000, the bigger the more noticible it gets 
int diceRoll = arc4random() % (spaceSet - 1);
if(diceRoll < (2 * (spaceSet / 10)))
    diceRoll = 0;
else if(diceRoll < (4 * (spaceSet / 10)))
    diceRoll = 1;
else if(diceRoll < (7 * (spaceSet / 10)))
    diceRoll = 2;
else
    diceRoll = 3;
```

Increasing the set of random and divinding it seems a good idea.

Comment: Its hard to see the different while playing so i tested to make a frequency of ammotype 2 to 70% but it didn't seem to occur more frequent than the others :/

Comment: That's why it's random, probability increase help but do not define occurence... keep using and eventually you will notice

Comment: By the way, to make it more noticible increase the set to, say, 100 or even 1000... it's just a small tweak in the code

Comment: Okay thanks! I will continue to test it out. Will using decimals work? like   `if(diceRoll < 0.2)`

Comment: decimals would increase percision but don't think this is a case for it... should keep it simple, check the new edit

Answer (score 0):

Careful...int diceRoll = arc4random() % 3 gives 3 different values: 0 to 2, as this will show:

```
int i, diceRoll;
for (i=1;i<20;i++){
    diceRoll = arc4random() % 3;
    NSLog(@"Roll %i",diceRoll);
}
```

"%" means "the remainder when you divide by", and there's no remainder 3.